# Ignite Transactional From DataStream Receiver not supported?

Tags: ignite

I am using igniteDataStreamer and would like to know if it is possible to use transactions from closures.

Unfortunately, when running from different IgniteDataStreamer threads for the same record to update in the cache(receive() method in StreamReceiver), Ignite does not throw any TransactionOptimisticException even though CacheConfiguration atomicityMode is TRANSACTIONAL.

```
try (Transaction t = ignite.transactions().txStart(TransactionConcurrency.OPTIMISTIC, TransactionIsolation.SERIALIZABLE)) { 
            try { 
                cache.putAll(update); 
                t.commit(); 
            catch (TransactionOptimisticException toe) { 
                LOG.error("TransactionOptimisticException Could not put all the profiles",toe); 
            } 
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data streamer is not transactional. To execute updates in a single transaction, they must be initiated on the same node and by the same thread. For more details and examples read here: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/transactions

Comment: Now another problem is if my application runs as client mode, then Ignite does not anymore throw TransactionOptimisticException in receive method. Could you please explain why?

Comment: got the reason why i was sending ignitetransactions instead of ignite instance itself.